# excluding a subdomain from htaccess redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, ssl, wildcard

I've searched stackoverflow before submitting this thread but I had no luck :-S

I've a website with a complex .htaccess file as below:

This part is for redirecting (X.2nate dot com --> 2nate dot com/api/x) and it's working well

```
########### API Redirection Section ##########

RewriteEngine On
 # Extract the subdomain part of domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.2nate\.com$ [NC]
 # Check that the subdomain part is not www and ftp and mail
RewriteCond %1 !^(www|ftp|mail|charge)$ [NC]
 # Redirect all requests to the original url  /blog
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://2nate.com/api/%1 [L]
```

This part is for redirecting non-SSL requests to SSL protocol:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

And this part is for redirecting with WWW to no-WWW address:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.2nate\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/2nate\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

and the problem is:

when I was trying to access "charge" dot mywebsite dot com (charge is a real subdomain in my host) I cannot access the related page and it's redirecting to main page!

I think problem is with this part:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.2nate\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/2nate\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

Because when I remove this part, everything is OK (except redirecting to non-WWW).

Any helps are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is actually this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://2nate.com/api/%1 [L]
```

**Since you're using `http://` in target URL it is not a silent rewrite but will become external redirect.**

Have your .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.2nate\.com$
RewriteRule ^ http://2nate.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# Extract the subdomain part of domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www)[^.]+)\.2nate\.com$ [NC]
# Check that the subdomain part is not www and ftp and mail
RewriteCond %1 !^(www|ftp|mail|charge)$ [NC]
 # Redirect all requests to the original url /blog
RewriteRule ^.*$ /api/%1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, but it's not working in the way I want.

It's just affecting Silent/External redirect (I don't want to change these settings).

I just want to be able access charge.2nate.com.

Comment: I have another real subdomain "blog"-dot-mywebsite-dot-com and it's working well.

Comment: I think now I am not getting your problem? Which URL is not working for you?

Comment: Also `https://charge.2nate.com/add-event.html` worked fine for me and it didn't change to main domain.